# run script on bitbucket on push

Tags: git, repository, push, bitbucket

I want to run a script that is located in the repository of the server.
How can i call that script from bash git command line. 
The purpose of the above is to run the script, then the script
executes some custom test programs. I want to run those test programs 
on the programs already on the server before pushing some new ones.
If this can be done, please, be thorough with your answer because 
I am completely new to git.

Comment: Did I get it right: You really assume, that bitbucket let you run scripts on _their_ servers?!?

Comment: Yeah I know it was a lame question. I just had to be sure because it's for an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like support for this has been added since this was asked and answered.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/register-maintain-hook-scripts/

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you can do this on bitbucket.  You have to do this before you push.

You might want to look into git hooks to run this on your system when you commit.

see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Yup. Pre-Commit-hook for test-scripts is a quite common use-case. Additional this will keep your local repository clean too.

Comment: Thank you for the link sir. Your help is much apprecieted